# Is it Possible to convert a set of numbers to their ASCII Char values?

Tags: delphi, char, ascii, chr, ord

I can convert a string into the Ascii values with spaces in between.

Example: "I like carrots"
To: 73 32 108 105...

But I'm trying to figure out a way to take those NUMBERS and convert them BACK into their ascii Chars.

I'm using the latest version of Delphi (embarcadero) and am new to coding so pls help me out :)

Comment: The answer is yes, but you have to reduce your problem to a specific issue that you're unable to solve. In other words: what have you tried so far?

Comment: You might already know this, but the ASCII character set consists of only 128 characters. So, for instance, none of the characters in `ÅÄÖαβγδεޗสჱꡤሞ턀∫∑∏∪∩∧∂⊕☃` is an ASCII character. The native Delphi character type since Delphi 2009 is `WideChar`, a 16-bit Unicode character.

Comment: It's quite interesting that you put two valid answers to your Q as tags! Yes, both `Char(65)` and `Chr(65)` return `'A'`. :)

Comment: Homework assignment to our community? ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Ord function in every character.
The Chr function returns the character for specified ASCII value.

Example

```
var
  s: string;
  c: char;

s:='I like carrots';
for c in s do
begin
   Writeln(ord(c));
end;
```

Comment: `Chr` also works for non-ASCII characters: `Chr($222b)` for the integral sign.

Comment: How is the code example related to the question asked?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
var
    S1 : String;
    S2 : String;
    A  : TStringDynArray;   // Add System.Types in uses
    N  : String;
    C  : Char;
begin
    // 'I like carrots' in ascii code separated by a space
    S1 := '73 32 108 105 107 101 32 99 97 114 114 111 116 115';
    A  := SplitString(S1, ' ');   // Add System.StrUtils in uses
    S2 := '';
    for N in A do
        S2 := S2 + Char(StrToInt(N));
    ShowMessage(S2);
end;
```

I don't know the complete problem but you could add code to check of valid input string.

Comment: (1) Why not use `S1.Split([#32])` instead? Then you need not include anything. (2) Building a string one char at a time is wasteful. Better to preallocate and then fill.

Comment: Consider using `TStringBuilder` instead of appending 1 `Char` at a time to the `String`, which is very memory-inefficient. And you can do away with the `TStringDynArray` if you use `Pos/Ex()`+`Copy()` instead to extract each delimited substring.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand RemyLebeau your suggestions are good of course, but they will make the code more complex for a beginner and will confuse him. The code I show does the job and is easily understandable. The OP will optimize his code once he master the basis and if there is any need (The question here looks like home work for a student).

Comment: @RemyLebeau The purpose is not about performance, but conversion to character/string. About performance, 1. TStringBuilder is [actually slower than naive string concatenation](https://www.delphitools.info/2013/10/30/efficient-string-building-in-delphi/) for small strings. IMHO TStringBuilder is an anti-pattern coming from the C#/Java world. And 2. the Char() expression makes an hidden conversion from char to string before appending - this is actually slower than the concatenation itself.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez: I'm also not a huge fan of the string builder, but I think we can all agree that `SetLength(S2, Length(A)); for k := 0 to High(A) do S2[i + 1] := Chr(StrToInt(A[k]))` is significantly faster than the code in this A for very large values of `Length(A)`. But of course @fpiette is completely right that his approach is easier to understand and in many cases more than fast enough.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know much about delphi, but take a look at this link: http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/Article.asp?Name=Text

In the Assigning to and from character variables section it demonstrates a function like so:
`fromNum := Chr(65);  // Assign using a function`.

If that doesn't work, you could consider building a large mapping of int->char. The beginnings of which is in that above website also near the top.

Comment: I'd not recommend you to use DelphiBasics; it contains too many inaccuracies and is not up to date. Also, the page you link to seems to be written before Unicode (last millennium). Furthermore, there is no such thing as "the Ansi character set" (not now, not then). Building an array is not necessary at all.